# In R, package xts, how would one iterate period subsetting over a list without throwing errors?

Tags: r, time-series, xts, quantitative-finance

Assume:

- list of n xts objects in `.GlobalEnv` with the suffix ".raw" (e.g: `ABC.raw`)
- have created a list of `.raw` names in a `list` (ie, `rawfiles <- ls(pattern="*.raw",envir=.GlobalEnv)`)

Would like to:

- `loop` or `lapply` through rawfiles and subset a particular timeperiod in each iteration
- for example, to write this as a single line would be: `new <- ABC.raw["T09:00/T10:00"]` if I wanted to subset `ABC.raw` from 9am to 10am each day.

The problem is:

- Doesn't seem to be an easy way of passing`["Thh:mm/Thh:mm"]` to a loop, apply or assign without causing errors.

Any ideas how to pass this?

In pidgeon code, I guess I'm looking for a working equivalent of:

```
for(i in 1:length(raw)){
    raw[i]["T09:00/T10:00"]
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any assistance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `get`.

`get(x)` retrieves the variable whose name is stored in `x`, so `foo<-1; get('foo')` would return 1.

```
for ( rawname in rawfiles ) {
    get(rawname)["T09:00/T10:00"]
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks...seems so obvious now! Appreciate the help.